# Arduino pinmode() as in/out to check DRAM IC data pin

Tags: arduino

I am trying to get my arduino to write and read into on a 4416 DRAM IC and I am not really familiar with arduinos.

Problem is the pinmode() function for the arduino is either OUTPUT OR INPUT, not both. And the 4416 data pin is a in/out pin.

What is the "right" way of doing this? Trying to get the same arduino pin to read and write the same Ic data pin with some tricky code?

Or using one arduino pin to read and another to write the same IC data pin?

Comment: I think the problem you are facing is more than just the pinmode. The 4416 DRAM requires 8-bit addressing and 4-bit data lines with a data read/write cycling time of 230ns, it also needs some refresh circuit to keep the memory, so you will need to design a circuit to interface with it even it is possible. Depend on your application, the easier way is to find some memory (not necessary DRAM) that can be communicated via SPI bus, or if you need extra DRAM because of Arduino's limited memory, find some other micro controller that has bigger memory, such as STM32 or ESP32 for your application.

Comment: Technically, this is not a question about software and therefore doesn't belong to SO. It may be better to post at https://electronics.stackexchange.com.